# Maximum call stack size exceeded in custom Image filter

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am looking for a way to fill an Image with an image pattern in a [**FabricJs**](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js) canvas, since there is not a built-in [image filter](http://fabricjs.com/image-filters/) to do this. Although my code is still in an early version, basically it should work(unfortunately it doesn't); 
All the eavy work is done by `applyTo` method, where I load an image, then fill an hidden canvas with a pattern. I noticed that there is a function (`source`) which fall in an infinite recursion:

```
var pattern = new fabric.Pattern({
   source: function () {
       fhc.setDimensions({
           width: smile.getWidth() + 5,
           height: smile.getHeight() + 5,
       });
       return fhc.getElement();
   },
   repeat: 'repeat'
});
```

I have prepared  a demo on [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/InferOn/q1Lmry6L/)

Could anyone help me to understand how to solve this issue?

```
(function (global) {

   'use strict';

   var fabric = global.fabric || (global.fabric = {}),
       extend = fabric.util.object.extend;

   fabric.Image.filters.ImagePatternEffect = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Image.filters.BaseFilter, {

       type: 'ImagePatternEffect',

       initialize: function (options) {
           options = options || {};

           this.img = options.img;
       },

       applyTo: function (canvasEl) {

           var w = canvasEl.width;
           var h = canvasEl.height;
           var hc = document.createElement('canvas');

           fabric.Image.fromURL('http://i.imgur.com/0Ks0mlY.png', function (smile) {
               debugger;
               hc.setAttribute('width', w);
               hc.setAttribute('height', h);

               var fhc = new fabric.StaticCanvas(hc);
               fhc.add(smile);
               var pattern = new fabric.Pattern({
                   source: function () {
                       fhc.setDimensions({
                           width: smile.getWidth() + 5,
                           height: smile.getHeight() + 5,
                       });
                       return fhc.getElement();
                   },
                   repeat: 'repeat'
               });
               var rect = new fabric.Rect({
                   fill: pattern,
                   width: w,
                   height: h
               });

               fhc.add(rect);
               fhc.renderAll();

               var ifhcContext = fhc.getContext('2d');
               var fhcImageData = ifhcContext.getImageData(0, 0, fhc.width, fhc.height);
               var fhcData = fhcImageData.data;

               var context = canvasEl.getContext('2d'),
                   imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvasEl.width, canvasEl.height),
                   data = imageData.data;

               for (var i = 0, n = data.length; i < n; i += 4) {
                   data[i] += fhcData[i];
                   data[i + 1] += fhcData[i + 1];
                   data[i + 2] += fhcData[i + 2];

               }

               context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

           });

       },

       toObject: function () {
           return extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {


           });
       }
   });

   fabric.Image.filters.ImagePatternEffect.fromObject = function (object) {
       return new fabric.Image.filters.ImagePatternEffect(object);
   };

})(typeof exports !== 'undefined' ? exports : this);


var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');


fabric.Image.fromURL('http://i.imgur.com/qaQ8jir.png', function (img) {
   var orImg = img;
   img.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.ImagePatternEffect({

       img: orImg,

   }));
   img.applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
   canvas.add(img.set({
       width: 300,
       height: 300,

   }));
}, {
   crossOrigin: ''
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i also use pattern image on my web application , in order to add it on objects, and it works.

All you need is this function **function loadPattern(url, seatObj)** where i pass the object which i want to add the pattern each time and the image(pattern) link.

here is the snippet :

```
       function loadPattern(url, seatObj) {
    //i use the loadImage function to load the image and pass it to the fabric.Pattern constructor

                    fabric.util.loadImage(url, function (img) {
        //i change the fill property of the object to the
        //image that i want to load on it as a pattern

                        seatObj.fill = new fabric.Pattern({
                            source: img,
                            repeat: 'no-repeat'
                        });
//refresh canvas and watch your image pattern on the object
                        canvas.renderAll();
                    });
                }
```

hope this helps, 
good luck

Comment: tanks to your reply, hoever if you take a look to my code you can see same code of your snippet. Btw, repeat: 'no-repeat' make a pattern a non-pattern ;)

Comment: hello, i believe that the code that i show above it is small ,quick ,it works and it is self explanatory. if it helps you with your issue just tick on my answer ,atherwise it ok. whoever else needs to add an image pattern on his objects he can use the code that i show above. cheers

Comment: your snippet its already in my code, the problem it's another, please read the question, I am trying to render a bitmap over a rectangle as repeated pattern, then apply this pattern over another image bit a bit, do you understand your code it's only a little part of the solution? Do you can read my code to see that the load of pattern in the rectangle it's already in place? cheers